# @Value not working even if key is resolved [Spring 4]

Tags: spring, configuration, annotations

My constants.java is like this:

```
package com.sample.utils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component(value="ConstantValues")
public class Constants {

    static {
        System.out.println("Class loaded: Constants");
    }

    @Value("${allowxmlvalue}") 
    private String logXMLString;

    public String getLogXMLString() {
        return logXMLString;
    }

    public void setLogXMLString(String logXMLString) {
        this.logXMLString = logXMLString;
    }

}
```

I am loading Application using spring boot like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("file:/home/ubuntu/config/properties/app.properties"),
    @PropertySource("file:/home/ubuntu/config/properties/util.properties")})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { 
        "com.sample.utils"  
         })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Sample {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Sample.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Sample.class, args);
        Constants cons = new Constants();
        logger.info("Print XML: "+cons.getLogXMLString());
    }
}
```

I can see following print in logs:

> 20:40:45,865 DEBUG PropertySourcesPropertyResolver:90 - Found key
>   'allowxmlvalue' in [URL
>   [/home/ubuntu/config/properties/app.properties]] with type [String]
>   and value 'print xml value'

But still Print XML: null is printed out, What I may be missing here?

Comment: If you create a new instance of Constants using the "new" operator, it will not be managed by Spring, so you can't use dependency injection. You need to load it from Spring's ApplicationContext instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the `Constants` instance yourself instead of getting the Spring managed bean. Obviously its fields won't have been processed by Spring.

So get it from Spring

```
ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Sample.class, args);
Constants cons = ctx.getBean(Constants.class);
```

or inject it into the `Sample` bean.